# How to import graph I made in desmos into TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So I got [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h1ebnmh7go?lang=fr) graph here, intended to illustrate the layercake representation of a measurable function, made in desmos. I'd like to take that into Ti*k*Z, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Plotting the function is easy, and I even have gotten as far as to depict the it's Riemann integration, through the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=$\R$, xlabel= $X$, xlabel near ticks,xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymax=3,ymin=0, xticklabels=\empty,extra y ticks={2.75,2.5,2,2.25,1.75,1.5,1.25,0.75,0.5,0.25}]
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, name path=f, thick, color=blue] {exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)};
\draw[black] (5.21,1.5) node {$f$};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta,fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<1.5,1.25<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),1.25,0)};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta,fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<1.25,1<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),1,0)};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta, fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<1.75,1.5<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),1.5,0)};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta,fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<2,1.75<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),1.75,0)};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta,fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<2.25,2<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),2,0)};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta,fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<2.5,2.25<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),2.25,0)};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta,fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<.75,.5<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),.5,0)};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta,fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<.5,.25<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),.25,0)};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta,fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<1,.75<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),.75,0)};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta,fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<3,2.75<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),2.75,0)};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, color=magenta,fill=magenta,fill opacity=.5]{ifthenelse(and(exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)<2.75,2.5<exp(-x^2/10)*abs(sin(deg(x^2))+x+1)),2.5,0)};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%LINHAS TRAÇEJADAS EM ORDEM CRESCENTE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {.25};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {.5};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {.75};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {1};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {1.25};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {1.5};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {1.75};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {2};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {2.25}; 
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {2.5};
\addplot[domain=-10:10,samples=500, dashed,opacity=.75] {2.75};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which yields the following:

[image]

There's nothing wrong with the code or with the graph, I merely would like to depict the horizontal layers as the desmos graph shows, which are only suggested by the dashed lines in my Ti*k*Z graph.

[image: fromDesmos]

Comment: Welcome. // Did you check; https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=desmos ?

Comment: I did, but couldn't find anything close to my situation, even though we got the same type of issue

Comment: Ok. How did you get the tikz statements. As export or manually? Can you use an image instead?

Comment: Manually. I don't want to use an image, wanna keep this consistent with the other pics in my work, talso tikz made.

Comment: Sorry, your posted code does not compile, and it's not obvious, which packages are missing. E.g. package pre seems to be unknown at ctan. Which installation do you use to compile it?

Comment: Just updated it with the necessary packages. Sorry, force of habit. The pre package is a pool of the basic stuff for any type of document.